# How do we calculate the trace over the matrix logarithm $\log((\sigma_2 \otimes I_{n/2})^T\cdot\Omega_{S^n})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, kronecker-product

How do we explicitly compute the curvature form $\Omega$ of the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{L.C.}$ for the $n$-sphere $S^n$?

> Thus, how do we calculate the trace over the matrix logarithm $\log((\sigma_2 \otimes I_{n/2})^T\cdot\Omega)$ for $\sigma_2$ the second Pauli matrix, and $I_{n/2}$ the identity matrix of dimension $n/2$?

Thanks in advance! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If by $TS^n$ you mean the tangent bundle of the $n$-sphere, for any manifold $M$ there's a homotopy equivalence $M \simeq TM$ given by contracting the fibers of the projection map

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [How do we compute the trace over the matrix logarithm $\log((\sigma_2 \otimes I_{n/2})^T\cdot\Omega)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307416)